Reseting single file and fixup to another commit
The situation is the following :
commit_A : contains fileA and fileB
commit_B : contains fileC and fileD

I want to move the fileA from the commit_A to the commit_B.
What I am doing most of the time is a interactive rebase, I mark commit_A as e (for edit), I then reset the commit, do a commit with fileA and redo the commit with only file B, then finish the rebase and finally I fixup the new commit with only fileA to commit_B.
My question is, is there any better way to do ? Because it doesn't seem optimal,
Thanks


is there any better way to do ?

I believe there is - it is mixed reset.
Let's imagine your head is on commit_B. The commands to execute are the following:

If commit_A is not the first commit in your repo, you need to reset
your head to state preceding to it: git reset [--mixed] HEAD~~
Now all the changes you made within the last two commits are in working tree, but not in stage area.

Stage fileB: git add fileB and commit git commit -m 'fileB'

Stage the rest: git add . and commit git commit -m 'A,C,D files'

If your old commits are already on remote repo, you have to rewrite history there too:
git push --force


Voila, it should work.
Usually git allows to do many things in different ways, so often it is just a matter of preference or how good you own the stuff (like in git checkout vs git switch).
The same is for rebase/merge, rebase/reset, et cetera.
For example, git rebase is often used for squashing commits, but it does not preserve dates (the result will have the date of the oldest commit), but git reset --soft doesn't have such problem.
If you are curious about what git reset does, then git-reset-demystified shines in revealing some git concepts and terminology.

If i got properly what you said, let's say I have :
B->C->D->A
If I do git reset HEAD~~~ I will end up with my HEAD on B, and I then i commit fileB it will be a new commit, but I still need to squash it with commitB.
And then I would need to re-do all the commits C, D and A which is not very ideal I think

The point of my question is the following, let's say you got :

cpp directory
include directory
And I do of commit for the modifications for cpp dir and then for the include one but if by mistake I put a file of cpp in the include commit, I'd like to move that file.
Not that this is a simple case where I only have one file to move and two commits, but it may happens I have more files to move and more commits between the two I'm considering


If you insist on your history to be clean, just git reset to commit before mistake, move your *.cpp in a proper dir, then git add **/cppdir/*.cpp and commit. And repeat the same for inlcude dir. git reset is about rewriting history, by resetting you remove all the commits happened after target one, but preserve your work you have done so far. If it is a personal project you are free to rebuild your history in a way whatever you want.

Yes well my point is that this will not preserve the commits after the mistake point (when i say dont preserve i mean the commit messages and the content).

Because with your solution i need to rebuild the entire tree while with a rebase and edit (what i am doing now) i only edit a single commit. My question was more is there a way to reset a single file from a commit and not the entiere commit

I don't think it is possible, but i might be wrong. Try to look at git filter-repo or its previous kinda obsolete analog git filter-branch. This is advanced stuff. It's better to just introduce new commit, that does the fix - you should not spend a lot of time for history. History is just a history.

In my case It's not just a student project or what, we need to have very clean history in my compagny, so no history is not just history.
